# Changed bottom bar in gnome to left, now both bars are gone. Can I use terminal to fix this?

Tags: command-line, gnome, settings

I don't even know if gnome just crashed or went hidden or what.

Comment: Try entering the following commands in terminal. `gconftool-2 --recursive-unset /apps/panel && killall gnome-panel`

Comment: The above commands may bring you back the panels which you have lost.

Comment: Thanks, but I ended up figuring out that if I restarted, both bars would come back for a short while, during which time I was able to simply delete the bottom bar (opening the properties dialogue to reposition it crashed things again), and then create a new one.

Comment: I'd test your recommendation, but I'm afraid I might break things even worse.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use an extension to change this in gnome-shell?  If so you can use the terminal to remove the offending extension from ~/.local/share/extensions/